# How can I disable the close button?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I need some help with figuring out how to disable/hide the close, minimize, and resize buttons in OS X Cocoa and Swift 2. Here's the code I tried. I know it's for the Title Bar, but I thought I'd try it anyway:

```
self.window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
```

Does any one know how to do that? I'm using Swift 2, OS X Cocoa, and Xcode 7.2. Thanks!

Comment: Directly in Interface Builder is not an option?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't, because I need it done when a button is pressed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Also try;

```
    self.window!.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.closeButton)!.hidden = true
    self.window!.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.miniaturizeButton)!.hidden = true
```

etc.

Comment: I'm getting the same error that I got with the other code: "Use of unresolved identifier 'window'"

Comment: @TDM Replace `window` with whatever variable name points to your window

Comment: @AaronBrager how do I set the variable to be equal to my window? Btw thanks for your help. I'm new to programming in Swift, so this site has been very helpful.

Comment: You probably need self.window!. I edited the answer.

Comment: For Swift 4, this should be changed to:
`self.window!.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.closeButton)!.isHidden = true`
`self.window!.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.miniaturizeButton)!.isHidden = true`

Comment: I recommend `.isEnabled = false` over `.hidden = false`. It just greys out the close button and to me looks better to the user.

Answer (score 13):

In Xcode 9.1 you can use following in the ViewController,

```
override func viewWillAppear() {

    self.view.window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
    self.view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    
    self.view.window?.styleMask.insert(.fullSizeContentView)
    
    self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.closable)
    self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.fullScreen)
    self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.miniaturizable)
    self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.resizable)
    
    //self.view.window?.isMovable = false
}
```

[image]

```
override func viewWillAppear() {

    self.view.window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
    self.view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    
    self.view.window?.styleMask.insert(.fullSizeContentView)
    
    //self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.closable)
    self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.fullScreen)
    self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.miniaturizable)
    self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.resizable)
    
    //self.view.window?.isMovable = false
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine in Xcode Version 11.4 beta 2 (11N123k) with storyboards.

Answer (score 3):

See the [NSWindow.styleMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSWindow/styleMask) property and the [Window Style Masks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Window_Style_Masks).

Clearing the NSClosableWindowMask, NSMiniaturizableWindowMask, and NSResizableWindowMask flags will remove all of the buttons from a window's title bar.

```
window.styleMask &= ~(NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the window part that says, "Use of unresolved identifier 'window'"

Comment: @Sulthan That is how you do it in Swift.

Comment: Swift 3 throws this: `Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two 'NSWindowStyleMask' operands`

Answer (score 2):

I find that the following effectively *disables* without completely hiding the close button:

`self.view.window?.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.closeButton)?.isEnabled = false`

Answer (score 2):

a side note: do NOT disable "close" red button: apple will reject app saying:

"The user interface of your app is not consistent with the macOS Human Interface Guidelines. Specifically:

Specifically, the red light was disabled."

:(

Comment: Good to know. That doesn’t matter if the app is not being sold on the App Store though

Comment: yes. I wrote to help some other happened to fall here :)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34886599/433373) above by @JohnElemans, this is what worked for me when **presenting modally using a storyboard segue** on macOS 10.15:

```
// On NSViewController.viewDidAppear()

if let window = self.view.window {
    window.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
    window.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
    window.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
}
```

I had to add the third line (`NSWindow.ButtonType.zoomButton`) to get rid of the **green** ('fullscreen') button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboards and you can change your window styleMask property  inside an IBAction or viewDidLoad as follow:

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first?.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask   // | NSClosableWindowMask |  NSMiniaturizableWindowMask  | NSResizableWindowMask
```

If you would like to enable them again just uncomment the rest of the style mask:

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first?.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask |  NSMiniaturizableWindowMask  | NSResizableWindowMask
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flutter， you can do like this：

```
import Cocoa
import FlutterMacOS
import window_manager


class MainFlutterWindow: NSWindow {
  override func awakeFromNib() {
    let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController.init()
    let windowFrame = self.frame
    self.contentViewController = flutterViewController
    self.setFrame(windowFrame, display: true)
  
  self.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
  self.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
  self.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true


RegisterGeneratedPlugins(registry: flutterViewController)

super.awakeFromNib()
  }

    
  override public func order(_ place: NSWindow.OrderingMode, relativeTo otherWin: Int) {
            super.order(place, relativeTo: otherWin)
             hiddenWindowAtLaunch()
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove those buttons by removing style masks,

```
window.styleMask.remove(.resizable)
window.styleMask.remove(.miniaturizable)
window.styleMask.remove(.closable)
```

Tested in **Xcode 14.1** and **Swift 5**

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.